# What is the SQL Server equivalent to Oracle's Virtual Private Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, security, owasp

What is the SQL Server equivalent to Oracle's Virtual Private Database (VPD)?

Answer (score 5):

For row/column level security and other aspects like fine grained access control in SQL Server you might want to check this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966395.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can create a VPD in SQL Server using VIEW objects. SQL Server has the USER system function which returns the database user similar to how Oracle does.